Godot4 - This function for damage effects from an enemy doesn't behave right
I am following a tutorial for a 2D platformer but the video is a couple years old so the version in the video v3.2. I am using 4. So far there were always comments to help out people who had Godot 4 but this had no comment. This function is supposed to throw you back and change the sprite color. The if statement is supposed to be the horizontal part of the jump back. If your position.x is less than (to the left) the enemy sprite, you jump to the left. If you're on the right side, you jump right.
func ouch(enemyposx):
    set_modulate(Color(1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3))
    velocity.y = -JUMPFORCE * 0.5
    
    if position.x < enemyposx:
        velocity.x = -800
    elif position.x > enemyposx:
        velocity.x = 800
    
    Input.action_release("move_left")
    Input.action_release("move_right")

The if part, for the left side, doesn't do anything. The right side works though. But if I change the elif to a negative value, it works on the left but not the right. Why is that? It doesn't make any sense.
I'm not sure what to tell you that I didn't say in the first part. I've tried messing with the values. I've even looked at every character to make sure I didn't misspell something.

hey print out the positions of both instances (player and enemy) and look if they are correct. Since you are not using global_position there could be a problem with diffrent origins (Position 0/0 for your enemy does not have to be 0/0 for you Player
